# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client not one

Tags: mysql, node.js

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:645:11)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:794:10)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:174:12)
at ServerResponse.json (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:278:15)
at Query. (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\csvimport.js:88:29)
at Query. (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Query._callback (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
at Sequence.end (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\JavaScript\LiveClass project\Backend\user-registration\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:149:8) {
code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwACh.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqfMd.jpg)
i my code i am using nodejs and mysql

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.